# How to Install Debian with GUI

Tags: debian, gnome, gui

I need to install Debian wheezy. I don't need to install all the packages. I tried netinst image, but I have no internet connection in my laptop to download a GUI. Is there a CD/DVD image of Debian INCLUDING a GUI (Gnome/KDE...)? Like Ubuntu CD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Debian distributes CD, DVD, and Blu-ray images. There are various methods to download them; see https://www.debian.org/CD/. There are also vendors who sell them, in case you don't have sufficient bandwidth to download the images yourself.

I believe CD1 should include an GNOME graphical desktop. There are CD1 variants for LXDE and KDE as well. DVD1 should include far more, I think all three (LXDE, GNOME, and KDE). You can also use multiple discs; if you download and burn the entire set, there are quite a few packages included, enough that you can reasonably use it entirely off-line.

If you want to know which disc a given package is on, see http://cdimage-search.debian.org/.

I'll also note that you can use the install CDs with an existing installation by adding CD sources to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` So, for example, if you've got a good install that's just missing a GUI, you can add DVD1 and then install the GUI.

(The full, all-packages set is, if you want to download it with jigdo: 67 CDs, 10 DVDs, or  2 Blu-rays.)

BTW: If you're looking for a CD to boot off of and use (not just install), you're looking for a [Debian Live image](https://www.debian.org/CD/live/).

Comment: Clear. Thanks a lot... I hope to download 'debian-7.7.0-amd64-kde-CD-1.iso'